# Tengo problemas al momento de hacer enrutamiento en laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

El problema ocurre cuando modifico la ruta

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/usuario', function () {
        return view('welcome');
});
```

El resultado es este para cualquier dirección que ponga:
[image: http://localhost/laravel/sistema/public/usuario]

Solo ejecuta bien cuando la ruta es la raíz

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
});
```

El Resultado muestra normal cuando está en la raíz
[image: http://localhost/laravel/sistema/public/]

Comment: Lo olvidé en la respuesta. Revisa que tu archivo server.php, no esté bloqueado por el antivirus. De hecho, localhost te dirige al public en laravel, por lo que no necesitas colocar /laravel/sistema/public; solo localhost, para acceder a la raiz del sitio. Saludos

Comment: haz logrado solucionar esto? tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Puede que en tu .env tengas una url distinta y por esto te está dando este error.
checa tu archivo.env, deberias tener algo como (con laragon):

```
APP_URL=http://my-app.test
```

entonces con la ruta qu estas declarando '/usuario', deberia retornar la vista welcome asi:

```
http://my-app.test/usuario
```

Si estas usando Xampp, creo que iría el nombre del localhost 127.0.0.1
que responde a localhost, entonces tendrías que colcar:
http://localhost/usuario

ejecuta el comando: php artisan serve. deberias dar con 127.0.0.1:8000 y colocas nuevamente la ruta 127.0.0.1:8000/usuario a la que quieres acceder

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: ya limpié la caché y no me funciona :( el .env  si tiene a localhost en la ruta APP_URL=http://localhost, más bien pienso que php.ini del xampp no tiene algo des comentado pero no se qué :(

Comment: ejecuta el comando:
php artisan serve. deberias dar con http://127.0.0.1:8000
y colocas nuevamente la ruta http://127.0.0.1:8000/usuario a la que quieres acceder

Answer (score 0):

Eso que te pasa es por tu ruta:

si te fijas en la URL de tu primera imagen: `localhost/laravel/sistema/public/usuario`

debería de ser `localhost/laravel/usuario`

Esto lo puedes solucionar de varias formas:

1.- Usando un virtualhost creandolo en xampp o wamp con el servidor local que trabajes.

2.- Modificando tu archivo .env para que la variable `APP_URL` concuerde con tu ruta de tu aplicación.

La manera más rápida, para mi, es crear un `vhost` como te dije en la primera opción, porque de esa manera, estableces la ruta de acceso directo a tu aplicación, y siempre va aaceder a `/public` de laravel.

Espero haberte guiado.

Un saludo